# Live Texturing using Vuforia

Tags: live, vuforia, texturing

I wanted to know if there is a possibility of doing live texturing in 3D model using vuforia.

If not live, can we at least pick the color from drawing book and apply the same color to our augmented 3D model?

Like done in the following video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmfXgvT9h3s

Comment: I am struck with the same problem. If you got something, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes it is very possible with vuforia. But that's not how you ask questions on stackoverflow...

Comment: I don't see if Vuforia would allow modification in their certain methodology of detecting the image, because texture detection would only be done in the mean time of detecting and augmenting the 3D model,

The way i see it that we may want to develop (or modify Vuforia) ARCamera according to our own requirement.
Can we do that?

Or can you discuss the way you see it?

And i am sorry if i bothered asking the question in a wrong manner, i am new here so maybe you could understand, my bad.